# Using Node.js lib on Front-end (Browserify)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I using Browserify to get js file of html-pdf Lib ( $npm install html-pdf )
The Browserify help me take html-pdf lib and all dependencies, but when I run it on web (front-end) it throw exception:

```
TypeError: childprocess.spawn is not a function
```

I think, the Browserify only help us to take all dependencies and source code of third-lib ... not include Node.js lib ( in this case is [childprocess](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/child_process.js)) , which is the third-lib needed.

Is there anyone know anout this, please help me, thanks

Comment: You can't do everything you can do in Node in a browser.

Comment: There are limits to what can be emulated or sensibly shimmed in the browser. The list of built-in Node modules that have some level of support is [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility).